# How to track internal redirect urls on Google Analytics User Explorer?

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress, php, user-experience

In our wp site the external urls replaced with internal links and when someone clicks on them they go to redirected external url, but those are not logged by google analytics user explorer. How to track those clicks?

Comment: There is no way to place Google Analytics code on the redirecting URL.   You'll need to look into putting tracking on the click rather than on the redirect.

Comment: Yup, just create a click trigger (all elements) and activate all "click" variables in GTM, than in preview mode you will see the variable that suits your need.

Comment: from which settings i can do that?